# Choosing between dnx451 and dnxcore 50 for Azure Web App in terms of functionality, performance, etc

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, dnx, dnx50

I am creating a new project that will run in Azure Web App on the new ASP.NET 5. We are not planning to run it on linux or anything like that, at least now. So the question is, should I try to keep both frameworks if possible just in case or I should prefer one of them. There are e.g. much less dependencies that I can use with dnxcore50 which is not so nice. So the main question is: are there any benefits of using dnxcore50 if running in Azure Web App, like: performance, stability, etc. over dnx451.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to start that I'm still the beginner in ASP.NET 5 (like the most other), so I didn't posted my answer before and you should ignore my reputation, because it's come from another subjects, which I know better.

I think that everybody, who switch to ASP.NET 5, ask the same question whether it does make sense to keep both framework in his projects. I try to post below *my personal* thoughts about the subject.

My personal choice is my short recommendation to you: **keep both framework till you find some really important reason to drop one from there**.

ASP.NET 5 is still not final. The strategy is not full fixed and it can be changed in a short time later. Just some examples. Previous beta versions have supported "Helios" as an option for hosting ASP.NET 5 applications on IIS. The option was dropped later (see [the statement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)). Even the name `dnxcore50` is renamed now to `dotnet5.4` at least in all internal Microsoft components (see [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98)). One can suppose that some other things could be changed in the future. Thus I think that putting all your eggs in one basket would be too dangerous now: **keeping of both frameworks could reduce the risk**.

The next thing, which I found, was the following. `dnxcore50` (`dotnet5.4` or CoreFX or .NET Core foundational libraries) don't support many features supported by .Net Framework. One important example for me was missing XSD Schema validation (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3633) and [here](http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/xmlschema-in-net-core/507)). I use XML only in combination with XSD Schema validation. I prefer JSON in the most other cases. Kipping of both frameworks in your project **could helps you to locate the parts of your code, which could be not yet implemented in CoreFX**. It could helps you to move the code in separate component or to change the implementation.

About the performance. One should distinguish potentiality of both frameworks from the current implementation. In general CoreFX was redesigned and decomposed. Many parts of one `mscorlib` was separated or removed (remoting, AppDomains and so on). It means that the performance of CoreFX should be better. Theoretically **the factored API can provide better performance**. Moreover one can more easy improve one parts of CoreFX and publish new version with improved performance. More modules instead of having one monolith gives us **the new way for improvement of the performance and for fixing the bugs**. On the other side **replacing of dependencies to new version could be origin of new compatibility problems and thus it increases the risk and could decrease the stability**. By keeping of both frameworks we can test whether the new problem exist in alternative framework. It allows us to suppose that the last changes of dependencies and not the last changes of our main code is the origin of new problems.

I can continue with pros and cons of the usage of every framework, but nodoby like to read long text and all my arguments forward me to the same practical decision: **keeping by default of both frameworks in my projects as soon as I would find out a real requirement to drop one from the frameworks**.

Comment: You will still have to chose only one to run on :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Yes, you have to choose one option during publishing on Azure, but you can easy change the choice if you hold internally both frameworks in your project.

Comment: Which one do you prefer to run in Azure then? Maybe you did some testing on which one performs better?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Sorry, but I didn't posted any productive solutions to Azure. So I'm a wrong person, who you should ask about it. I would just choose the cheapest one and to monitor whether the required performance and the total cost would be enough. It could be good way to ask new question about publishing on Azure. The readers who have experience in the subject could share his knowledge with you.

Comment: Well I suppose it behaves pretty much the same way in Azure as on ordinary Windows server :) So it would be nice to know which one you prefer to run you solution if you have such experience (regardless of Azure)

Answer (score 1):

No major advantages really so far.

This might change in the future and why I'm planning to target both (CoreCLR and .NET 4.6). A lot of investment is being spent in CoreCLR but also on Docker and Service Fabric.

Just my 2 cents.